# VirtualBox settings

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox

VirtualBox gives us any tool to verify how much CPU or
memory, a particular running application is using?
During settings, we can forse the virtual machine to use a limited
amount of RAM and a fixed number of cpu cores, but is there a way to 
control these parameters?
I'm running an Android emulator on a VirtualBox on a core i7 pc,
but what is the speed of the emulated cpu?

Any hint would be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual box only run the OS, and that's the OS that run the application. So that is on the OS side that you should look. Maybe there exist some debugging tools on android that can tell you this.

There is no real CPU speed, given the fact that the virtual machine is emulating, and not simulating the hardware.

Comment: You can control the maximum percentage of HOST CPU that the virtual machine can use in the settings for the machine. That is found under: Settings -> System -> Processor. The slider called "Execution Cap." In my experience, it causes the host to slow down also. Clement is correct about app usage. That is the Guest OS's responsibility.